# What is the difference between Node.SelectNodes(/*) and Node.childNodes?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

```
        string XML1 = "<Root><InsertHere></InsertHere></Root>";
        string XML2 = "<Root><child1><childnodes>data</childnodes><childnodes>data1</childnodes></child1><child2><childnodes>data</childnodes><childnodes>data1</childnodes></child2></Root>";
```

Among below mentioned two code samples.. usage of childNodes doesn't copy all the child nodes from XML2. only `<child1>` is being copied.

```
        string strXpath = "/Root/InsertHere";

        XmlDocument xdxmlChildDoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument ParentDoc = new XmlDocument();
        ParentDoc.LoadXml(XML1);
        xdxmlChildDoc.LoadXml(XML2);

        XmlNode xnNewNode = ParentDoc.ImportNode(xdxmlChildDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Root"), true);

        if (xnNewNode != null)
        {
            XmlNodeList xnChildNodes = xnNewNode.SelectNodes("/*");
            if (xnChildNodes != null)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode xnNode in xnChildNodes)
                {
                    if (xnNode != null)
                    {
                        ParentDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(strXpath).AppendChild(xnNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**code2:**

```
    if (xnNewNode != null)
    {
        XmlNodeList xnChildNodes = xnNewNode.ChildNodes;
        if (xnChildNodes != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlNode xnNode in xnChildNodes)
            {
                if (xnNode != null)
                {
                    ParentDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(strXpath).AppendChild(xnNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ParentDoc.OuterXML after executing first sample of code:

```
<Root>
    <InsertHere>
        <child1>
            <childnodes>data</childnodes>
            <childnodes>data1</childnodes>
        </child1>
        <child2>
            <childnodes>data</childnodes>
            <childnodes>data1</childnodes>
        </child2>
    </InsertHere>
</Root>
```

ParentDoc.OuterXML after executing second sample of Code

```
<Root>
    <InsertHere>
        <child1>
            <childnodes>data</childnodes>
            <childnodes>data1</childnodes>
        </child1>
    </InsertHere>
</Root>
```

Comment: Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes after reading these links you will get the answer.

Comment: @RamSingh, they won't explain why code fails to copy `<Child2>` node.

Comment: have tried "SelectSingleNode(String, XmlNamespaceManager)" this method?

Comment: Can you please let me know .... what it has to do with XMLNamespace?

Comment: Please read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx

Comment: @RamSingh, I have worked heavily with XML, XSD and XSLT (ofcourse XPath).... I know the definition of NameSpace. Here Namespace doesn't come into picture!

Comment: @RamSingh, I appreciate your help and support

Comment: please take a look of answers for this question, they clarify the significance of these methodologies :)

Comment: thanks i have already studied the answer. And that will help me too in future.

Comment: infant programmer'Aravind': You shouldn't be doing this kind of processing using DOM -- XSLT provides the necessary expressive power, ease and convenience for such processing.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, Hello :) Yes agreed! But I wasn't sure how to pass two (XML) strings  to XSLT. As far as I know, we can use document (a file from location) from XSLT.

Comment: infant programmer'Aravind': Hello :) You can pass one of the documents as a parameter to the transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a clearing of what Anders G posted, with more through explanation.

I am surprised the foreach  does not fail (Throw Exception) in this situation, but hell.

In code1.
1. Create a NEW COLLECTION of nodes
2. Select nodes to it
3. append to other node => removing from original collection, but not the newly created one.
4 you are removing the node you are adding from the newly collection.

in Code2
1. Reference the ORIGINAL node collection
{child1, child2}
2. append 1st Node away to another collection => removing it from the original collection
{child2}
3. now when the foreach at index 1,  it see that it passed the end of the collection. and exit.

this happens a lot when changing a collection that is subject to iteration.
but most the time, the IEnumerator is throwing an Exception when such happens.

hope i made it all clear

Answer (score 3):

I have done some debugging of the code, and it shows that `xnNewNode.ChildNodes` initially also returns 2 child nodes. After one iteration in the loop, the first child is however removed from `ChildNodes`, and therefore the loop ends prematurely.

If you want to use the `ChildNodes` property, one workaround is to "transfer" the child node references to an array or list, like this:

```
var xnChildNodes = xnNewNode.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().ToArray();
```

**UPDATE**

As Tomer W pointed out in his answer, when using [XmlNode.AppendChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild) the inserted node is also removed from its original location. As stated in the MSDN documentation:

```
If the newChild is already in the tree, it is removed from 
its original position and added to its target position.
```

With `SelectNodes` you have already created a new node collection, but with `ChildNodes` you are accessing the original collection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and observed, that whitespace nodes seem to have a value attached to the node, which is not the case with other nodes (at least in my application).This method removes the whitespace nodes from the node.ChildNodes list:

```
private List<XmlNode> findChildnodes(XmlNode node)
    {
        List<XmlNode> result = new List<XmlNode>();
        foreach (XmlNode childnode in node.ChildNodes) 
        {
            if(childnode.Value == null)
            {
                result.Add(childnode);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question, `Node.childNodes` is **All** of the child nodes, whereas `Node.SelectNodes(/*)` is all of the child nodes that match `/*`. Only XML elements will match `/*`, so any attributes, CDATA nodes, text nodes, etc will be excluded.

Nevertheless, the problem occurs because you are changing the collection of nodes while while iterating over them. You cannot do that. The select nodes method returns a list of references to nodes. This is why is works.